# Office Open XML - how to add additional Information to Presentation?

Tags: powerpoint, openxml, spreadsheetml

I would like to store akey / value pair into my presentation (basically a GUID to know if I have seen the file before).
I know that excel and word have extended properties, which can be used to store this kind ofinformation.
But I am unsure if I can store similar Information in a Powerpoint-Document?
Could someone point me to the right documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I store key/value pairs in Shape.Tags.  I can see them in X.pptx\ppt\tags\tag*n*.xml. Use VBA to save something there and you should be able to find it in the XML, or in the code generated by the Open XML SDK.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is a very good idea!
Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

To add to Oliver's response, shapes, slides and presentations can all have tags.

For example:

```
Sub Example()
  With ActivePresentation
    .Tags.Add "SEENBEFORE", "YES"
  End With
End Sub

Sub AnotherExample
  With ActivePresentation
    If .Tags("SEENBEFORE") = "YES" Then
        MsgBox "I've seen it all before."
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```